# Error in Apostrophe update version to latest one

Tags: apostrophe-cms

While upgrading latest version to 2.83.1 -

/app/node_modules/apostrophe/index.js:74
        throw err;
        ^

Error: forbidden
    at Object.self.docBeforeUpdate (/app/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-docs/lib/api.js:699:15)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/apostrophe/index.js:516:20)
    at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)

Comment: Not getting this error on a fresh install of 2.83.1 .. can you post a demo repo that reproduces the error?

Comment: Issue got resolved by deleting the existing database and installing the latest version 2.83.1. Thanks Stuart!